# Error establishing a database connection - WordPress and mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

My WordPress website often has the error `Error establishing a database connection`.

Previously, I used `sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql` and `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` to fix it. However, this time, they could not work anymore; `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql` returned

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start
```

And `mysqld --verbose` returned

```
180120  3:24:48 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180120  3:24:48 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/chengtie.lower-test
180120  3:24:48 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.58-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 20724 ...
180120  3:24:48 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/chengtie.lower-test
180120  3:24:48 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/chengtie.lower-test
180120  3:24:48 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

180120  3:24:48 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180120  3:24:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
180120  3:24:48 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
180120  3:24:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180120  3:24:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180120  3:24:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
180120  3:24:48 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180120  3:24:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
180120  3:24:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180120  3:24:48 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
180120  3:24:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
180120  3:24:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
180120  3:24:48 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
180120  3:24:48 [ERROR] Aborting

180120  3:24:48 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Does anyone know how to make my website back?

Comment: `InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12` - looks like your instance is out of memory? how much memory does the droplet have and how much is available when you try starting mysql?

Comment: @Oliver the droplet has `512MB`, there are other small websites running on it as well. How can I see how much memory is available when I try starting mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your droplet does not have enough memory available to start MySQL. See the error `InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12` - MySQL is failing when trying to allocate ~130MB of memory.
Run `free -m` to check how much memory is available to applications.

You can address this issue in two ways:

1. Increase the size of the droplet. This will cost you more money.
2. [Add (more) swap space to your droplet.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) This will most probably impact performance but saves you money.

Comment: indeed, I increased the memory of the droplet from 512MB to 1G, it works now... thank you...